# Code Stuck in a Loop and Need to Strip Characters from a File

Tags: python

I am trying to code a program that asks the user what the value of a variable is, opens a file,  searches for a word, and then checks to see if the number after that word is equal to the user inputted variable, which means I have to get rid of the spaces in between that specific word and the number after it. Unfortunately, I am having some problems with my code and can’t figure out why it will not work. I am sorry if the question I am asking is fairly simple, I haven't coded in python in over a year and am extremely rusty to say the least.

```
def getword1(prompt):
    while True:
        filestr1 = input(prompt)

def getword2(prompt):
    while True:
        filestr2 = input(prompt)

def getword3(prompt):
    while True:
        filestr3 = input(prompt)

def openfile(prompt, missingfileerror):
    """Opens a file"""

    while True:
        try:
            filestr = input(prompt)
            return open(filestr)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(missingfileerror)

uservariable1 = getword1("What is the value of the first variable? If not applicable, please enter 0")

variable1search = ("Word1", uservariable1)

uservariable2 = getword2("What is the value of the second variable? If not applicable, please enter 0")

variable2search = ("Word2", uservariable2)

uservariable3 = getword3("What is the value of the third variable? If not applicable, please enter 0")

variable3search = ("Word3", uservariable3)

file = openfile("Enter the name of the file that contains the variables.")

if uservariable1 == ("0"):
    print("No uservariable1")
else:
    if variable1search in file:
        print("The variable values match.")
    else:
        print("The variable values do not match.")

if uservariable2 == ("0"):
    print("No uservariable2")
else:
    if variable2search in file:
        print("The variable values match.")
    else:
        print("The variable values do not match.")

if uservariable3 == ("0"):
print("No uservariable3")
else:
    if variable3search in file:
        print("The variable values match.")
    else:
        print("The variable values do not match.")

file.close()
```

When I run the code in terminal, the code asks my first question, but after I give it an answer, it is stuck in a loop of asking me the same first question over and over again. I also cannot remember how to properly use the .strip() function in this instance. I am searching for a string as my variable because the value of the variable will include a comma, such as 750,000 or 2,000. If I can strip the comma and also maybe a $ sign from the opened file, I would be able to search for an int instead of a string. Thanks for your time!

Comment: you are using `while True` with no break. It is like going into black hole with no snacks. From what I see in your code there is no need for `while` loop please check the use of while loop

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `while` loop from the `openfile` function. It has no use.

```
def openfile(prompt, missingfileerror):
"""Opens a file"""
    try:
        filestr = input(prompt)
           return open(filestr)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(missingfileerror)
```

NB. One other slight problem with your setup is that you should always close files that you've opened. But in this function, you cannot do that anymore, because the code after `return` will not be executed (if there are no errors).

Another problem is that your code is not DRY (look up the principle). You've duplicated many functions that are almost identical. There is probably a way to do this in 1/3 of the code.

Another problem is that you have added `while` loops in `getword<x>` as well, they are not needed either.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first point, the code is getting stuck asking the first question repeatedly because of your `while True` in `getword1()`.

There is an also an awful lot wrong with the rest of your code:

- Unnecessary while loops everywhere
- You don't return anything from your `getword()` functions, (so `uservariable1` etc. will end up as `None`)
- You don't need 3 separate `getword()` functions, one would do
- Actually, you don't really *need* any, (if you're not going to do any validation), you could just write `uservariable1 = input("What is the value ...")` etc.
- `if variable2search in file` will never return `True` - you need to iterate over the file's contents

If you *do* want to do some user input validation, you could try something like:

```
def getword(prompt):
    while True:
        foo = input(prompt)
    if <some evaluation criteron here>:
        return foo #Return input and break out of while loop
```

I suggest reading up on [`while`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) and [file access](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), as a minimum.

Finally, try writing your code in small chunks and proving each bit works before moving on to the next, it's easier to debug that way.